# Word to describe object that can be physically passed through

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word to describe something that can be physically passed through like a ghost, mist, or a gas. Initially, I was thinking of the work transparent, but I feel like this is better used to describe something that is see through.

Comment: There are a lot of answers that say stuff like intangible or immaterial. Doesn't those mean it can't be touched? Is it what you're locking for?

Comment: in game secondlife.com such objects have **phantom** set to true

Comment: Presumably liquids would also fall into this category. Its not a single word, but the best term I can think of is "not solid".

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Borrowing from Carl Sagan's [*The Dragon in My Garage*](http://www.godlessgeeks.com/LINKS/Dragon.htm), which suggests this word for specters:

> [***incorporeal***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/incorporeal) - having no physical body or form

(Definition from Merriam-Webster.)

I have to take issue with *permeable.*  A sieve is permeable, a sponge is permeable, but unless you're a molecule or a virus or something similarly small you can't pass through.

Comment: In technical writing, permeable is often modified to indicate what can/can't get through.  The difference between a sponge and a sieve is one of degree, not kind...

Comment: Technically, I agree with you, but it's not to easy to imagine a person passing through an ordinary sponge or sieve. Perhaps in sci-fi, where people have been miniaturized.

Comment: +1 ***Much*** better. Ghosts are not sieves.

Comment: Captures the essence of the matter in question. :-)

Comment: A sieve is not *permeable* to people, so permeable is still the perfect match to the title of the question, though *incorporeal* matches some other qualities the body of the question details.

Comment: Downvote because incorporeal is something used to describe something without a corporeal body. A mist or gas is not expected to have a body so the comparison is weak.  Incorporeal is usually reserved for ghosts and souls and such 'sentient' things that are not in a body 'at this time'.

Answer (score 38):

How about *ethereal* or *penetrable*?

M-W:

> [*ethereal*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ethereal):
>   lacking material substance
>
> [*penetrable*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/penetrable):
>   allowing someone or something to pass through or enter : able to be
>   penetrated

It's not hard to imagine passing through anything *ethereal*.

It would not be unreasonable to consider a ghost, gas, or mist *penetrable*, in fact infinitely so.

Note: @Drew mentioned *penetrable* in a comment.

Comment: +1, but would also add 'intangible', 'insubstantial', and/or 'impalpable', since they don't mean that there is no physical matter, just that solid objects can't interact physically with that matter in any significant way. Would remove 'ethereal' and avoid 'incorporeal', 'unsubstantial', and 'immaterial', since those imply the absence of physical matter - which works for ghost but not mist or gases.

Comment: +1 for ethereal, since it seems to come up often in descriptions of ghosts.

Answer (score 31):

The word you're looking for is *permeable*.

Ghosts are permeable, a gauze curtain is permeable, a cloud is permeable.

[Permeable](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/permeable)

> allowing liquids or gases to pass through

Comment: That's the answer. In addition, something *penetrable* can be passed into (but not necessarily passed through).

Comment: Good to know that ghosts are permeable. Do they have a pore size? Other properties of permeable materials? Tortuosity, perhaps?

Comment: That would have been my answer too. +1. @RichardKayser, lol.

Comment: It seems to me that the OP is looking for a word to describe the characteristic of ghosts, gases, and mists that allows objects to pass through them, not the property of materials that allow ghosts, gases, and mists, or liquids, to pass through them. *Permeable* is perfect for the latter, wrong for the former. Perhaps the OP can weigh in.

Comment: -1, Something that is permeable can be passed through because there are (possibly tiny) holes, not because the matter doesn't stop movement. This seems completely wrong for a ghost.This describes a strainer or cheesecloth. The definition you linked specifically says "having pores or openings that permit liquids or gases to pass through"

Comment: @DCShannon: hmm, it appears that the dictionary definition of *permeable* pretty strictly limits it to things that allow liquids or gasses to pass through, not objects in general.  I thought *permeable* was the obvious answer based on the title (but maybe not for ghosts), but http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/permeable very strongly associates it with filtering.  OTOH, other definitions aren't so strong.  http://www.dictionary.com/browse/permeate

Answer (score 22):

Permeable is a good word. But if you're looking for variety, I'd suggest *intangible*. In comics, some suprheroes(e.g. Martian Manhunter) have this super-power where objects and people can pass though them as if they don't exist, helping them to dodge bullets etc. It's referred to as *Intangibility*.

intangible
ɪnˈtan(d)ʒɪb(ə)l/
adjective

```
1.
unable to be touched; not having physical presence.
"the moonlight made things seem intangible"
```

If the context is ghosts or other spiritual entities, you can also use words like *spectral* or *incorporeal* to convey the same meaning.

Comment: +1, despite saying permeable is good. Intangible is absolutely the right word for this. Came to this page to post that as an answer.

Comment: I don't think permeable is a good fit, but intangible is the right word.  Here's  a link to TVTropes that shows it's used that way in fiction:  http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Intangibility

Answer (score 8):

To expand on @stevesliva answer:

[Immaterial - TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/immaterial)

> 2. Having no material body or form.

Comment: *Immaterial* is a good fit to the request but it's perhaps more commonly used in the sense of definition 1 from your link: *Of no importance or relevance; inconsequential or irrelevant.* If you're going to use this word you need to make sure the context makes clear which sense you mean.

Answer (score 8):

As an IT guy, I feel compelled to add **[traversable](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/traversable)**

> capable of being traversed
>
> [traverse](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/traverse):
>   a. To travel or pass across, over, or through: *a ship traversing a channel; light traversing a window.*

**Traversing** is more broad than *"passing through"*. Even if maybe it's not the exact meaning you are looking for, sometimes it can be the most appropiate word.

Comment: I was going to suggest *transitable* but this is much better. I think it it what I was looking for.

Comment: I think it's a bad choice for a word here. Traversable merely suggests that you can travel through the length, breadth, height of an object. Not pass through as though the object itself didn't exist. 

You traverse through an array of elements because it's traversable. If the array was intangible or incorporeal or ethereal, you'd always hit a null pointer exception.

Answer (score 5):

A book I enjoyed years ago called [Calling on Dragons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_on_Dragons), by Patricia C. Wrede, described a character that became "[insubstantial](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/insubstantial)", fitting your desired description exactly.

> a :  lacking substance or material nature - Merriam-Webster

Answer (score 1):

fluid: it means gas or liquid.

"a substance that has no fixed shape and yields easily to external pressure; a gas or (especially) a liquid."

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/fluid

Comment: Hey downvoter, please give some reasoning.

Comment: Not my downvote, but a ghost is not a fluid.  The OP wants a term that applies to a weird mix of stuff.

Answer (score 0):

One other way you can reference such an object is as "medium":

> The intervening substance through which sensory impressions are conveyed or physical forces are transmitted

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/medium

Comment: While true that most intangible things are mediums (as air is a medium for sound and even the void is a medium for light), not every medium is intangible (a copper wire is very much tangible, and as your own definition states, a wall is a medium for the force of a wrecking ball) and accidentally being a medium for some sensory impression is not what defines a ghost's insubstantiality.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the word ***transpirable***

This is defined by [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/transpirable) as:

> *To emit or give off waste matter, watery vapor, etc.,* ***through the surface, as of the body or of leaves.***

**OR**

> ***To escape,*** *as **moisture** or **odor (or "gas")**, through or as if* ***through pores.***

Alternatively, you could use ***respirable*** (regarding ghosts or mists), as defined by the [Merriam-Webster:](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/respirable)

> *Fit for breathing; also: capable of being **taken in** by breathing.*

Hope this helps :)